# Why isn’t the viewpager being recognised on the fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I’m trying to use a tabbed activity within a fragment, so a fragment with two other fragments. I keep getting the NullPointerException for the viewPager object, which has already been mapped by the right id. Whats gone wrong ?

```
public class BookFragment extends Fragment {
    

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_books, container, false);

        PageAdapter pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), 1);
        pageAdapter.addFragment("Pending", new PendingFragment());
        pageAdapter.addFragment("Scheduled", new ScheduledFragment());

        ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager_books);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

        TabLayout tabs = view.findViewById(R.id.book_tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return view;
    }
}
```

The fragment Layout ***(fragment_books.xml)*** being inflated;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".views.bookhub_navigation.ui_fragments.books.BookFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/book_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/pending_tab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pending" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/scheduled_tab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Scheduled" />
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager_books"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It keeps giving a NullPointerException when the id pager_books is in the right view heirarchy which is the fragment_books.xml file.

The error log

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setAdapter(androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference at com.immers_ltd.views.bookhub_navigation.ui_fragments.books.BookFragment.onCreateView(DateFragment.java:58) at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)

Comment: Check import library of ViewPager matching or not.

Comment: is it `PageAdapter` or `PagerAdapter` ?